# passing multiple parameters to php function from post?

Tags: php, jquery

If I have something like this

```
$.post("<?php localhost/site/foo/1123?>", callBackFoo);
```

It passes 1123 to foo function and foo function echos something back to callBackFoo

I want to know how I would add another parameter to foo so it take 1123 as arg1 and something else as arg2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Something like that" would cause a syntax error. Unexpected T_CONSTANT localhost on Line 1 (or something). Is that `localhost/site/foo/1123` getting echo'd by PHP there? If you are getting 1123 as a parameter you must be using some routing pattern of some sort. Which one?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear how you're handling your variables.

Can't you just do `localhost/site/foo?arg1=123&arg2=456`

Then get the arguments in PHP using `$arg1 = $_GET['arg1'];`

Answer (score 0):

Just read jQuery API documentation:

> Example: Request the test.php page and send some additional data along
>   (while still ignoring the return results).
>
> `$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`
>
> Example: Pass arrays of data to the server (while still ignoring the
>   return results).
>
> `$.post( "test.php", { 'choices[]': [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } );`

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/